# Post to Facebook with picture / URL wrong

Tags: php, facebook, post, hyperlink, image

Having trouble getting the posts to /me/feed to come out right:

http://www.facebook.com/dokuot/posts/359233024150001

Basically, that's how I'd like it to look, except the name of the post (which is also the URL) is pointing to the picture instead of the URL.

However, if I add a link to the parameters the visual changes to a link, which severely limits the number of characters I can post with the image. (Aka, no good).

**Is there anyway to make the title's href be different than the image?**

Here's my code for that particular post:

```
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $token,
    'caption'   => ""Sólo los sueños y los recuerdos son verdaderos, ante la falsedad engañosa de lo que llamamos el presente y la realidad."",
    'description'   => "Alejandro Dolina",
    'picture'       => "http://www.dokuot.com/autor/Alejandro_Dolina.jpg",
    'name'          => "http://www.dokuot.com/frase/4506",
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Of course, I've now switched the caption and the description to make use of the longer field, but the point stil persists that the title of the post links to the picture.

I'd also accept as an answer a way to bypass the 350 something character limit for the description on a link, which is my main issue at the moment with links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to make the title's href be different than the image?

You will have to give the `link`parameter if you want the “headline” to point some place specific.

If you just supply an image and no link, it will point to that image’s address. No way around that.